# How to extract current branch name only name from git log command

Tags: git, github, git-log

How to extract current branch name from git log

How to extract current branch name from git log

when I use the **

```
log -n 1 --pretty=%d HEAD
```

**
then the following output is showing
(HEAD -> branch1, origin/branch1 , orign/branch3 , origin/branch4 etc....)

But I want to extract only the current branch name from the git log, Can someone please help ?

**Limitation:**
I want to achive this only by using **git log ** command.

Comment: What's the reason of this limitation? Is this some kind of homework? ^^

Comment: No Romain, I am using gitRevisionPlugin to get the build information of the application, so when I deploy the app in the server, the head is detached, and when I run the commands like "git branch –show-current" getting empty.

Comment: In the future, when asking for help implementing the solution you're attempting to some problem, please describe the problem you're facing. Until you're likelier to answer questions on the subject than ask them odds are high the right answer is another approach that will work better.

Comment: OK so your limitation was in fact not that at all. Just explaining the reason would be been clearer for everyone.

Comment: Thank you for your time, Romain, I could achieve this using "log --no-walk --decorate-refs=refs/ --pretty=%D".

Answer (score 2):

So, from comments,

> when I deploy the bundle in a dev environment, the head is detached and when I run the commands like (git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD , git branch --show-current ) returning empty

what you're really trying to do is find some ref that points at the current checkout? If `HEAD` isn't attached to it, its not "the current branch", it's just a maybe-related name that points at the same commit.

And there's a bundle involved? What's really going on here?

To find the usual shorthand for refs that point at the current checkout,

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' --points-at HEAD
```

or if you don't mind scraping comma-separated lists

```
git log --no-walk --decorate-refs=refs/ --pretty=%D
```

and to restrict it to listing just local branches, add `refs/heads` to the f-e-r or change the log option to `--decorate-refs=refs/heads`

Comment: to complete the `git for-each-ref` command, if you are looking specifically for branches, you can also use : `git branch --format='%(refname:short)' --points-at HEAD`

Answer (score 0):

Pipe your output to `sed` to grab only the part you want :

```
git log -1 --pretty=%d | sed -E 's/^.*HEAD -> ([^\,]*)\,.*$/\1/'
```

(`HEAD` is implied by default, you don't need to explicitly ask for it)

Comment: Thanks Romain for your time, But when I run the above command, I am getting the output as below ((HEAD, origin/develop, develop) but I need only develop

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I know of is:

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
```

That will write the current branch name only.

Comment: That's the real pragmatic answer. I tried to accept the (still unexplained) limitation but of course this is clearly better ^^

Comment: when I deploy the bundle in a dev environment, the head is detached and when I run the commands like (git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD ,  git branch --show-current ) returning empty

Answer (score -1):

We can use the --show-current option of the git-branch command to print the current branch’s name. Here's how:

$ git branch –show-current

Comment: *Limitation: I want to achive this only by using **git log ** command*